# Sugar CRM api showing blank page without any error

Tags: php, soap, sugarcrm

I am following the following link just to see if sugar api makes the connection with my sugar crm

http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/03_Developers/100Web_Services/100Soap_API/100Examples/100PHP/Logging_In_-_SOAP_and_PHP/

I've adone everything correctly there i.e added proper login details, made a call to the correct nusoap library files.

But when I check my login file there it is showing a black page, there is no error there in the files.

I've check the error log file and it is showing the following error:

[25-Mar-2014 15:42:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
[25-Mar-2014 15:42:50 UTC] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_mysql.so' - /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/pdo_mysql.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Can anyone help me out what exactly the problem is.

**Just updated the question:**

```
$query = "accounts.name = 'testaccount'";
 $get_entry_list_parameters = array(

             'session' => $session_id,
             'module_name' => 'Accounts',
            'query' => $query,
             'order_by' => '',
             'offset' => '0',


          'select_fields' => array(
    'id',
          'name',
          'phone_office',
          'phone_fax',

     ),

     'link_name_to_fields_array' => array(      

     ),

             'max_results' => '5',
             'deleted' => '0',
             'Favorites' => false,
);

$get_entry_list_result = $client->call('get_entry_list', $get_entry_list_parameters);

echo '<pre>';
print_r($get_entry_list_result);
echo '</pre>';
```

Its giving me the account id, i am not sure how to retrieve that single value in single php variable so that I can assign it to my case.

Thanks

Comment: Hi. Try to set the max_results to '1'. In this way you will take the only record. $account_id = $get_entry_list_result[0]->id

Comment: Tried that but unfortunately it is not showing any value to me there

Comment: Sorry, it should be this way: $first_account_id = $get_entry_list_result['entry_list'][0]['id']

Comment: Hi Antonio, its working now, I can now be able to pull up and create the records in my sugar crm, thanks for the help.

Comment: Hi. I took inspiration from your question to write a post on my blog. At the time the post is in Italian only. http://www.dontesta.it/blog/blog-2/crm/sugarcrm-case-management-system/ Bye.

Comment: Okey that's great, other will get help from this too, it would be great if you can write one in English also.

Comment: Hi Antonio,I just stuck on the same problem again i.e blank page when i run my soap app for my online sugar crm